# codeigniter3 doesn't allow me to use this way, but Ci2 was working fine, to call a method of one controller to other controller

Tags: php, mongodb, frameworks, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

This is first controller
**1. Controller A**

```
class A extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function custom_a()
    {
    }
}
```

This is second controller
**2. Controller B**

```
class B extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function custom_b()
    {
            require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/a.php'); //include controller
            $aObj = new a();  //create object 
            $aObj->custom_a(); //call function
    }
}
```

Working fine with CI2 but after migrate to Ci3 its throw exception error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error Message: Class
>   'CI_Mongo_Db' not found Filename: public_html/system/core/Common.php
>   Line Number: 196

I am using MongoDB as database with CI3.

Comment: I know already that we can do it with library and as well as using helper function but I don't want to do that way, As per my case i want to do this way, by calling controller function into other controller.

Comment: You might not like it, but your only choices are a custom library that any controller can use or a helper.

Comment: @DFriend but its was working with CI2 but not with CI3, I don't understand why?

Comment: My Both controller have big script line of code and the function used many places and I can't put them on as library or helper. Another solution apprpeciated.

Comment: The v2 ability to call one controller from another was a bug. Think about it this way. There can be only one center in a circle and that is what a controller is - the center of the program's structure. I can think of no reason why any code in a controller could not be moved to a library.

Comment: There is another option. Create a base controller (`MY_Controller`) that has the code needed by multiple other controllers.

Comment: Ok, I will try other solution and let you know the final answer...

Comment: Yes we can also "There is another option. Create a base controller (MY_Controller) that has the code needed by multiple other controllers."   FOR NOW I MADE HELPER FUNCTION AND CALL THEM, THANKS :)